# LLVM-Polly 4.0, Auto-OpenMP for median filter

Tags: c, clang, llvm

I tried to compile the following simple code with llvm and polly.

```
main() {
  ...
  for(i=1; i<N-1; i++) {
    for(j=1; j<N-1; j++) {
      B[i][j] = median(i,j);
    }
  }
  ...
}

int median(int i, int j) {
  float median_v[9];
  int di, dj, m;
  m=0;
  for(di=-1; di<=1; di++) {
    for(dj=-1; dj<=1; dj++) {
      median_v[m++] = A[i+di][j+dj];
    }
  }      
  qsort(median_v, 9, sizeof(float), cmp);
  return median_v[4];    
}
```

Using:

```
> clang -O3 -mllvm -polly -mllvm -polly-parallel -lgomp median.c
```

But the execution time is 12s with 99% cpu time (N=5000).

Instead, if compiled with gcc or clang forcing OpenMP pragma on principal for cycle:

```
...
#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)
for(i=1; i<N-1; i++) {
...
```

the execution time drops to 3s with 330% cpu time.

Why is not Polly able to parallelize the main cycle?